# How to arrange/sort by unique sequences?

Tags: r

A) Here is my data frame **arranged** by plate:

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text="
plate phase  score
A      1      1
A      1      1
A      1      1

A      2      1
A      2      1
A      2      1

A      3      2
A      3      2
A      3      2

B      1      1
B      1      1
B      1      2

B      2      1
B      2      1
B      2      3")
```

B) Goal: I want to order it by both plate first and **then** phase but **sequentially** (see below how the rows are ordered alphabetically by plate but sequentially by phase

```
   plate phase score
   <chr> <int> <int>
 1 A         1     1
 2 A         2     1
 3 A         3     2
 4 A         1     1
 5 A         2     1
 6 A         3     2
 7 A         1     1
 8 A         2     1
 9 A         3     2
10 B         1     1
11 B         2     1
12 B         1     1
13 B         2     1
14 B         1     2
15 B         2     3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to create a sequence variable grouped by 'plate', 'phase' and `arrange` on it along with 'plate' and 'score'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(plate, phase) %>%
   mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   arrange(plate, rn, score) %>% 
   select(-rn)
# A tibble: 15 x 3
#   plate phase score
#   <chr> <int> <int>
# 1 A         1     1
# 2 A         2     1
# 3 A         3     2
# 4 A         1     1
# 5 A         2     1
# 6 A         3     2
# 7 A         1     1
# 8 A         2     1
# 9 A         3     2
#10 B         1     1
#11 B         2     1
#12 B         1     1
#13 B         2     1
#14 B         1     2
#15 B         2     3
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[order(plate, rowid(phase), score)]
```

Answer (score 2):

```r
df[with(df, order(plate, ave(phase, phase, FUN = seq_along), phase)),]
#>    plate phase score
#> 1      A     1     1
#> 4      A     2     1
#> 7      A     3     2
#> 2      A     1     1
#> 5      A     2     1
#> 8      A     3     2
#> 3      A     1     1
#> 6      A     2     1
#> 9      A     3     2
#> 10     B     1     1
#> 13     B     2     1
#> 11     B     1     1
#> 14     B     2     1
#> 12     B     1     2
#> 15     B     2     3
```